# Realm DB unit test fail with error : "make_dir() failed"

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Am trying to execute test-cases using realm as my db store that am using in my application. Saving and executing the operation on an iOS device is working as expected. But am trying to run the unit-test cases in the simulator, the test-cases fails with the following error,

```
frameworkname.realm::find failed with error:Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4700477-****-****-****-065C******7F2/data/Documents/frameworkname/frameworkname.realm.management': make_dir() failed: No such file or directory.
```

I tried setting the Devices directory read-write permission to everyone, but still it throws the same error.

Comment: Hmm, how is the file path URL for that Realm file being generated exactly? Is it a relative path?

Comment: The filepath for this file is internal I assume. I do not set anything specific filepath for this file.

Comment: Why don't you try an in-memory test configuration? I use it for testing my apps and it works really good, specially because you don't interfere with data saved by the simulator itself. Take a look to https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#testing-and-debugging

Comment: @ShaneD The error message indicates that you attempted to open a Realm file in a not-writable directory. It seems the Realm file in the framework's bundle directory? If so, you should copy the file to a writable directory first, or open read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

`make_dir() failed` in the error message indicates that you attempted to open a Realm file in a not-writable directory.

Copying the file to writable url might resolve the issue like the following:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let realmURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("data.realm")
try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL, to: realmURL)

config.fileURL = realmURL
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = try! Realm()]
```